# NODEJS TEDIOUS reconnect

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious

I've connected to an SQL Server using Tedious/NodeJS. Connection and queries are working fine (in command-line) until the connection (LAN or WIFI) goes down.

Then, the nodejs script in cmd throws an unhandled error event .

How I can catch disconnections and reconnect, while keeping the script running in console?

```
events.js:174<br>
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event<br>
      ^<br>
ConnectionError: Connection lost - read ECONNRESET<br>
    at ConnectionError (dev node\node_modules\tedious\lib\errors.js:13:12)<br>
    at Connection.socketError (dev node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1297:54)<br>
    at Socket.socket.on.error (dev node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1128:14)<br>
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)<br>
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)<br>
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)<br>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)<br>
Emitted 'error' event at:<br>
    at Connection.socketError (dev node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1297:12)<br>
    at Socket.socket.on.error (dev node\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1128:14)<br>
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]<br>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)<br>
```

Win7
node V10.16.0
Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit)

Comment: Use a try catch block. It will keep the server alive. Also, share a snippet of the code that's failing, so others have a better understanding of your use case and problem.

Comment: Thanx Marcus for reply. Anyway I found that I  forgot connection.on('error') wich solved my problem.

Comment: How did you do the reconnect? I tried using on error but I can't reconnect. Do you have an example?